# What are the default JPA annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a project that uses JPA and hibernate, and I've just noticed that the entities don't have any relationship annotations such as @ManyToOne, @OneToOne, etc.
So my question is, does JPA/Hibernate adds a default annotation for each case?

Here is an examples

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "strategy")
public class Strategy extends TradingEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
@Valid
private List<Rule> rules;
```

Does JPA add a @OneToMany annotation by default to this property ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no "default" annotations, but some JPA implementations (e.g the one I've been using, DataNucleus) are intelligent enough to work out that if a field is a Collection of an Entity type then it is a OneToMany/ManyToMany and to default things like fetching and cascading etc. Clearly you cannot assume that your implementation will have this logic so should put what you need (and "JPA" does nothing, it is your implementation that would do it). Clearly also, you can specify the same info in XML so could have no annotations

Comment: Thanks. I'm using hibernate. Does anybody know what is the case with that implementation.?